# Iterating through a doubly linked list backwards. C++

Tags: c++, iterator, doubly-linked-list

Using my current method I get a run time error, "list iter not derefrencable".
The for loop looks like:

```
for (iter = the_list.end(); iter != the_list.begin(); iter--)
{
    if (assignment >= (*iter)){ // If the assignment being added is greater than assignment being pointed to in the list, add it after
                                // the assignment being pointed to
        if (!(assignment == (*iter))) // If the assignment being added is not a duplicate, add it
        {
            iter++; // Increment the iterator to add the assignment to place after the one it was compared to
            the_list.insert(iter, assignment); // Insert the assignment at the iterator's position
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your first value of iter should be the item before end() and not end() itself.

Comment: The *standard* `end()` iterator is actually one *beyond* the end of the container. Dereferencing it leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: So, would it be possible to avoid undefined behavior by making the for loop look like... `for(iter = the_list.end()-1; iter != the_list.begin(); iter--)` ?

Answer (score 6):

The most straightforward way is to use reverse iterators:

`for (iter = the_list.rbegin(); iter != the_list.rend(); ++iter)`

Comment: Thank you, I've never heard of reverse iterators before. I will look into using those.